# jupyter extensions: ipycache: How to clear cache

Tags: caching, jupyter-notebook, ipycache, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

[Jupyter extensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) is  a set of extensions to Jupyter Notebook that allow for all sorts of customizations. [ipycache](https://github.com/rossant/ipycache) allows caching the contents of computed cells to save computation time [as in this example](https://github.com/rossant/ipycache/blob/master/examples/example.ipynb).

Is there a way to explicitly invalidate the results of a cache and force recomputation appart from manually going and deleting the file?

After a quick search didn't find e.g. an "explicitly invalidate cache" param,
though i remember having seen something some years ago at an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the README.md of `ipycache`:

> Use the --force or -f option to force the cell's execution and overwrite the file.